# Por que no me esta dejando hacer la relacion Uno a Uno con usuarios y terceros?

Tags: java, mongodb, netbeans, spring-boot, spring

estoy intentando hacer una relación One To One de Usuarios a Terceros usando SpringBoot y MongoDB, para ello estoy siguiendo este ejemplo de este artículo que encontré en la web [[JPA] Relación One to One basada en clave foránea](https://sacavix.com/2021/04/jpa-relacion-one-to-one-basada-en-clave-foranea/)

Ya realicé todos los pasos tal cual aparecen en el artículo, pero no me está mostrando los datos de la relación, en la tabla de Usuarios en campo terceros me aparece null, Este es mi JSON del resultado de Get Usuarios como se puede observar terceros esta null

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "alias": "juan12x",
        "email": "felipe@gmail.com",
        "contrasena": "1234",
        "terceros": null
    }
]
```

Este es mi modelo de Terceros

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(value = "Terceros")
@Data
@Table(name = "Terceros")
public class Terceros {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private String email;
    private String genero;
    private Integer telefono;
    private String pais;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "Terceros")
    private Usuarios usuarios;
}
```

Controlador de Terceros

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Terceros;
import com.trabajoGrado.service.TercerosService;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TercerosController {

    private final TercerosService tercerosService;

    @PostMapping("/terceros")
    public void save(@RequestBody Terceros terceros) {
        tercerosService.save(terceros);
    }

    @GetMapping("/terceros")
    public List<Terceros> findAll(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
        redirectAttrs
                .addFlashAttribute("mensaje", "Agregado correctamente")
                .addFlashAttribute("clase", "success");
        return tercerosService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/terceros/{id}")
    public Terceros findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return tercerosService.findById(id).get();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/terceros/{id}")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        tercerosService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("terceros")
    public void update(@RequestBody Terceros terceros) {
        tercerosService.save(terceros);
    }
}
```

Servicio de Terceros

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Terceros;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.trabajoGrado.repository.TercerosRepository;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TercerosService {

    private final TercerosRepository tercerosRepository;

    public void save(Terceros terceros) {
        tercerosRepository.save(terceros);
    }

    public List<Terceros> findAll() {
        return tercerosRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Terceros> findById(Integer id) {
        return tercerosRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        tercerosRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Repository Terceros

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Terceros;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TercerosRepository extends MongoRepository<Terceros, Integer>{ 
    
}
```

Modelo de Usuarios

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document(value = "Usuarios")
@Table(name = "Usuarios", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"))
public class Usuarios {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String alias;
    private String email;
    private String contrasena;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tercero_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Terceros terceros;

}
```

Controlador de Usuarios

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Terceros;
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Usuarios;
import com.trabajoGrado.service.TercerosService;
import com.trabajoGrado.service.UsuariosService;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UsuariosController {

    private final UsuariosService usuariosService;

    @PostMapping("/usuarios")
    public void save(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios) {
        usuariosService.save(usuarios);
    }

    @GetMapping("/usuarios")
    public List<Usuarios> findAll(RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
        redirectAttrs
                .addFlashAttribute("mensaje", "Agregado correctamente")
                .addFlashAttribute("clase", "success");
        return usuariosService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/usuarios/{id}")
    public Usuarios findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return usuariosService.findById(id).get();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/usuarios/{id}")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        usuariosService.deleteById(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("usuarios")
    public void update(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios) {
        usuariosService.save(usuarios);
    }

}
```

Servicio de Usuarios

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Usuarios;
import com.trabajoGrado.repository.UsuariosRepository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UsuariosService {

    private final UsuariosRepository usuariosRepository;

    public void save(Usuarios usuarios) {
        usuariosRepository.save(usuarios);
    }

    public List<Usuarios> findAll() {
        return usuariosRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Optional<Usuarios> findById(Integer id) {
        return usuariosRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public void deleteById(Integer id) {
        usuariosRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Repository de Usuarios

```
import com.trabajoGrado.model.Usuarios;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsuariosRepository extends MongoRepository<Usuarios, Integer> {

}
```

¿Que debo de arreglar para que muestre todos los de datos terceros en el JSON?

Comment: Prueba poniendo:@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,.......)

Comment: No me funciona sigue igual

Comment: Prueba utilizando solo la etiqueta @DBRef y quitas "@OneToOne" y "@JoinColumn", supuestamente el repositorio determinara que es una relación uno a uno. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html

Comment: le cambie "@OneToOne" y "@JoinColumn" por la etiqueta @DBRef y sigue igual me sale null

Comment: ¿alguna recomendación o algo que pueda hacer?

Comment: ¿La frase: "MongoDB es una base de datos **no relacional**" significa algo para ti? Todo lo que intentas hacer con SpringBoot está muy bien para bases de datos relacionales, excepto para aquellas que no lo son, como MongoDB. Por lo cual, lo que debes cambiar es la forma de pensar y la forma en que quieres establecer las *relaciones*. En MongoDB puedes crear *referencias* entre documentos y justamente a eso debe apuntar tu diseño. Saludos